# VideoView Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm working on application that have two `Views` one is UI and other is `VideoView`.
UI thread is used until some events happen and then I want to `setContentView` to `VideoView`, but I got error on setting content view from UI to `VideoView`. For VideoView I use code below:

## Java

```
setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
VideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
String path= "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.vid;
VideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
VideoView.start();
```

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is error that I'm getting:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 0:**
Code from UI thread:

```
public class View extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
    
    Thread Thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder SurfaceHolder;
    boolean Play;

    public View(Context context){
        super(context); 
        SurfaceHolder=getHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(Play){
            
            if(!SurfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue; 
               //drawing
            if(something)
                Video();
        }

    public void Pause(){
        //called from onPause()
        Play=false;
        while(true){
            try {
                if(Thread!=null)
                Thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    Thread=null;
    }

    public void Resume(){
        //called from onResume()
        Play=true;
        Thread = new Thread(this);
        Thread.start();
    }

    public void Video(){
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
        VideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        String path= "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.vid;
        VideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        VideoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently you interact with widgets from the wrong thread. Do you have asynctasks or handlers or threads?

Comment: I have several `Threads` and `AsyncTasks`.

Comment: Guess we'll have to see more code. Is it possible that above piece of code is called from such a thread or asynctask?

Comment: I call above code from UI thread.

Comment: Then post the entire stack trace, and the corresponding piece of code. The Exception seems straightforward enough, but you'll have to elaborate a litte.

Comment: Ok, I'll post some more code.

Comment: And one more thing, I kill thread and then `setContentView` to `VideoView`. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I posted more code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `setContentView()` from the non-UI-thread.

```
public class View extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(Play){
            if(!SurfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            //drawing
            if(something)
                Video();
        }
    }

    public void Resume() {
        //called from onResume()
        Play=true;
        Thread = new Thread(this);
        Thread.start();
    }

    public void Video(){
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
       /* more code */
    }
}
```

`onResume` is called, which creates a new `Thread` (`Thread = new Thread(this);`) which you start, so `void run()` is called (remember, from the non-ui-thread which you just created). `run()` calls `video()`, which, in its turn, calls `setContentView()`. Voila, you called `setContentView()` from the non-UI-thread.

You shouldnt let a view implement `runnable`, let alone let a View manage a Thread. It is managed by the UI-thread, no other. A possibility might be to get the context from the view and use the `runOnUiThread(Runnable r)` method, but better yet: let the UI-thread do UI-work like showing video's.

```
// I think even this might work. Not 100% sure, I do this out of the top of my head.
public void onResume() {
    if (condition)
        getContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                video();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What is difference between regular `Thread` that I'm using and `Thread` in solution that you're suggested?

Comment: @acac97 runOnUIThread runs the runnable on the UI-thread and not on a non-UI thread.